# a square inscribed right triangle

Tags: geometry

I recently came across this problem.

[image]

The hypothenuse of the triangle has a length of 4, is base (highlighted in green) a length of x and the last side (highlighted in red) a length of y

I found this two equations to solve the problem.

First of all, $x^2+y^2=16$ (considering Pythagore's theorem).
Then you can easily find a relation such as $x.y = x+y$ using either Thales' theorem or the fact that the right triangle include two little triangle of heigth 1 and of base x and y respectivly.

So, you have the system :

(1) $x^2+y^2=16$

(2) $xy = x+y$

Which you can solve, but you have to solve a fourth degree equation...

I still think there is some more elegant solution.

Maybe somebody can find one.

Comment: I did not understand why $xy=x+y?$I googled thales theorem also.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x+y=\alpha,xy=\beta$. Then, you have
$$(x+y)^2-2xy=16\iff \alpha^2-2\beta=16$$and
$$\alpha=\beta$$

So, you can get $\alpha\gt 0$ by solving
$$\alpha^2-2\alpha=16.$$

Here, note that $x,y$ are the roots of 
$$t^2-\alpha t+\alpha=0.$$

So, we have$$x,y=\frac{\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2-4\alpha}}{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt{17}\pm\sqrt{14-2\sqrt{17}}}{2}$$
where $\alpha=1+\sqrt{17}\gt 0$.

Comment: I think this is much more elegant than solving the 4th degree equation, thanks.

Comment: @user3656801: You are welcome.